# Settings "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE" and "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING" issues with Azure functions on an App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I'm currently trying to get the configuration right for some Azure functions. These functions are running under an App Service Plan.

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account) if I'm running an Azure function in an App Service Plan then I **DO NOT** need to have the following settings:

- WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING
- WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE

However I'm finding that removing the settings causes the app to start up with no available functions with the following message:

```
"No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. 
If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make 
sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your 
startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.)."
```

When I re-add the settings the function continues to work however I'd like to understand why these settings should be needed if I'm using an App Service Plan.

Comment: done, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade to the latest `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` (1.0.26 as of today) and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Service.Bus` (2.1.0-beta4 if running on full framework).

Also, according to your description, I do not know how to you deploy the function. Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1453) that deploying Azure Function app's via `Terraform` and get the same problem with you.It seems that it is a [Function app consumption plan bug](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/1515).

Comment: Thanks Joey, I'll give the update a go. We are deploying via terraform, but it should be with an App Service Plan.

Comment: Yes, have you view the [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1453) which get the same problem with you with app service plan.

Comment: Yes, this looks like it's the issue, thanks very much for highlighting! What I find interesting is that even though it's related to setting up the functions using terraform. Removing the settings through the portal breaks the function too.

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same problem. I have deployed the function app using azure bicep and added below app settings:

1. WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING
2. WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET
3. Azurewebjobstorage

and my function app was throwing Service unavailable. The moment I removed the setting WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING it started working.

It doesn't matter how you deploy the function app and storage account what matters is the setting "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING" on dedicated app service plan deployed function app.